# MAC address in Compact Framework

Tags: compact-framework, mac-address

How can I get the MAC Address using only the compact framework?

Answer (score 5):

1.4 of the OpenNETCF code gets the information from the following P/Invoke call:

```
    [DllImport ("iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern int GetAdaptersInfo( byte[] ip, ref int size );
```

The physical address (returned as MAC address) I think is around about index 400 - 408 of the byte array after the call. So you can just use that directly if you don't want to use OpenNETCF (why though? OpenNETCF rocks more than stone henge!)

Wonderful P/Invoke.net gives a full example [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi/GetAdaptersInfo.html).

Oh and to properly answer your question:

> only using the Compact Framework

You cant. That's life with CF, if you want some fun try sending data with a socket synchronously with a timeout. :D

Answer (score 2):

Here are the **first three hits** from a Google search for "MAC address in Compact Framework:

1. http://arjunachith.blogspot.com/2007/08/retrieving-mac-address-in-compact.html
2. http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=920417&SiteID=1
3. http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=188787&SiteID=1

Did none of those help?

Two out of three point to [OpenNETCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/) as a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the registry, try to find your adapter MAC Address under the `LOCAL_MACHINE\Comm\PCI\***\Parms\MacAddress`.

It may be a quick and dirty solution that doesn't involve the use of WMI or OpenNETCF ...

Comment: That would be a complete luck situation if it's there.  I just checked 4 devices, including one that actually has a PCI bus, and none of them have the MacAddress in the registry.  Querying the value from NDIS is the only reliable way to get this.

Answer (score -1):

Add a reference to System.Management.dll and use something like:

```
Dim mc As System.Management.ManagementClass
Dim mo As ManagementObject
mc = New ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
Dim moc As ManagementObjectCollection = mc.GetInstances()
For Each mo In moc
    If mo.Item("IPEnabled") = True Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add("MAC address " & mo.Item("MacAddress").ToString())
    End If
Next
```

Comment: .Net CF (Compact Framework) does not have the `System.Management` namespace.