# how to get MAC address from Windows-mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

how to get MAC address from Windows-mobile using C# code ?

thank in advance

Answer (score 4):

please go through below pasted links hope this will help you to find the mac address of the device

[MAC address in Compact Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814/mac-address-in-compact-framework)

[How to Get MAC address programatically in c# for a windows mobile 6.0 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143323/how-to-get-mac-address-programatically-in-c-for-a-windows-mobile-6-0-device)

Answer (score 4):

```
      [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern int GetAdaptersInfo(byte[] info, ref uint size);

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets the Mac Address
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>the mac address or ""</returns>
  public static unsafe string GetMacAddress()
  {
     uint num = 0u;
     GetAdaptersInfo(null, ref num);
     byte[] array = new byte[(int)((UIntPtr)num)];
     int adaptersInfo = GetAdaptersInfo(array, ref num);
     if (adaptersInfo == 0)
     {
        string macAddress = "";
        int macLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(array, 400);
        macAddress = BitConverter.ToString(array, 404, macLength);
        macAddress = macAddress.Replace("-", ":");

        return macAddress;
     }
     else
        return "";
  }
```